# How to get string and store into array then compare with a list

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Please see my test case below which I want to automate with Selenium Webdriver and Java:

1. Get names of all the columns.
2. Store it in an array or string.
3. Soft Assert with expected values.

(specifically 14 columns to be compared)

So what I am trying to do here is, I have a webpage which has a table. In this table I want to verify the column names present and compare it with my expected column names as per stated in the requirement.

```
//Get no of columns and store it into columnText variable
for (int i=0;i<noOfColumns;i++)
{
    columnText = tableColumns.get(i).getText();
    for (int j=0;j<noOfColumns;j++)
    {
        //SoftAssert for each column text for all 14 columns
        softassert.assertEquals(columnText, "abc");
        softassert.assertEquals(columnText, "def");
        .
        .
        softassert.assertEquals(columnText, "xyz");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question? See [ask]. Tell us what you want to do, show what you have tried, and show the results. Hint: questions hidden in the title are not really part of the question text.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. people on this forum appreciate if you have tried everything possible from your end still not able to resolve the error. In addition to the link mentioned by @jdv also go through [Help Center >> Asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we get all the texts from your columns.

```
   List<String> texts = tableColums.stream().map(a-> a.getText()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

You can then add your needed assertions into a list e.g.

```
List<String> toBeAsserted = new ArrayList();
toBeAsserted.add("abc"); etc etc
```

so then you can make me more dynamic:

```
texts.stream().filter(a-> toBeAsserted.stream().forEach(b-> softassert.assertEquals(a,b))).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Hope I understood your question correctly.

Comment: I tried implementing this but I am getting "texts" all in one List. I need them to be verifiable. For example:

softassert.assertEquals(texts[0], "def");
softassert.assertEquals(texts[1], "xyz");

Comment: @Shashank you want to assert all texts with all possible assertions right??? made an edit, try like that

Comment: thank you, it worked for me. I had to store the expected result in a String[] array and then I compared it.